Webots Simulation Scale
What is the simulation scale used in webots, I want to add solidworks pieces but it is too big for my webots environement.

If you want to scale meshes from SolidWorks then you can use the Transform node: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/transform

yes i know but in order to have a simulation that reflect reality i would like to know how much is the scale difference to apply it in the node

Typically, the CAD models are exported in mm or cm, so 0.001 or 0.01

Webots generally expresses things in meters. (It shows up a few times in the documentation [ex], but I cant find a specific point where they state this explicitly.)
However, more generally, Webots is built upon the Open Dynamics Engine, so as long as you're consistent with your units, it will function properly.

What units should I use with ODE?

Short Answer: Metric, MKS (Metre-Kilogram-Second), thus your lengths will be expressed in meters, masses in kilograms, and timestep in seconds.
Slightly Longer Answer: "SI Units" or "The international system of Units", http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/ SI units is the technical term for Meter-Kilogram-Second. By always using SI units in calculations, you'll always get SI units out at the other end; you won't end up with nasty multipliers.
Longer Answer: technically, ODE doesn't use specific units. You can use anything you wish, as long as you stay consistent with yourself. For example, you could scale all your values by Pi, and everything will be fine. Being consistent with yourself is what SI units is; remember though that you multiply everything by pi, then your acceleration will include a pi^2 factor. This only gets uglier as it goes... stick with meters-kilograms-seconds
Longer, Slightly Sillier, Imperial, Answer: Furlongs per fortnight per hour is a perfectly accurate and meaningful description of linear acceleration, but trying to work out how far you've travelled in three minutes at that acceleration starting at zero gives you a lot of ugly multipliers.


- ODE Wiki
